# init: Id "2" respawning too fast

Tags: centos5, inittab

I've just updated a CentOS 5.10 box to 5.11 with all the latest patches and rebooted.

Following the reboot I'm now getting the below error message every few minutes:

> init: Id "2" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes

Line 2 of /etc/inittab reads:

> 2:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty1

Which looks consistent with other CentOS 5.11 servers.

I can see a running /sbin/mingetty process in ps aux with a recently started time and cannot see any other signs of the process crashing.

How can I trace the cause and/or rectify this.

Comment: Any errors in syslog? Is there a /dev/tty1?

Comment: Only entries in /var/log/messages (which is syslog on Centos I believe) is the init.. one shown above
ps aux shows:
>root     xxxx  0.0  0.0   1756   460 tty1     Ss+  16:49   0:00 /sbin/mingetty tty1

Comment: No error messages on the actual tty1 (the first text console)? Same permissions and on tty1 as say tty2?

Comment: When I look on the console there is just the same message repeated:
`INIT: Id "2" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes`

Comment: Maybe you could `strace /sbin/mingetty tty1`?

Comment: strace outputs a whole load of stuff but finishes with 'nanosleep({5, 0}, {5, 0})               = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?'
Is there something specific I should be looking for?

Comment: Was hoping for an error around the end of the trace. Blind debugging is no fun. For example on ubuntu I get `tty1: no controlling tty: Operation not permitted` a few lines before the exit. But default on ubuntu is getty which works.

Comment: Which begs a question: is mingetty default on centos? If not, switch to getty or whatever is default

Comment: I've just tried running strace on the "live" mingetty process and just got the below as it died and was respawned. I believe mingetty is the default on CentOS, /sbin does have agetty but no sign of getty it'self
`strace -p 30819
Process 30819 attached - interrupt to quit
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
Process 30819 detached`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a centos server around and I'm pretty much out of guesses. Especially if only tty1 is not working.

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of anyone reading this with the same issue. My resolution after much research and experimentation was that this is a virtual machine which doesn't have multiple windows.

As a result I have remmed out the below line in /etc/inittab

`#2:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty1`

Doing so has resolved the issue for me on this system and another one in each case a CentOS 5 system which started reporting this following a recent patch (inc Kernel) cycle.